# JRadioButton: How to overload an abstract method

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement ActionListener so that my GenderIsStored method of my GenderGUI class can record the number of times a user selects each JRadioButton that represents a gender, with each iteration of the loop in the driver class of my program. However, I cannot get my GenderGUI class to compile properly, due to the fact that I cannot figure out how to override the abstract method. The GenderCount class is implementing the ActionListener interface, which is abstract. Originally, I thought that in order to compile correctly, I would have to implement all the methods inside the parent interface (which is ActionListener), but the same problem occurred. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

```
public GenderGUI() 
{
    GenderChoice = new JLabel ("Select your gender below: "); 

    Male = new JRadioButton ("Male"); 
    Female = new JRadioButton ("Female"); 

    ButtonGroup GenderGroup = new ButtonGroup(); 
    GenderGroup.add (Male); 
    GenderGroup.add (Female); 

    GenderCount listener = new GenderCount (); 
    Male.addActionListener (listener); 
    Female.addActionListener (listener); 
    primary = new JPanel(); 
    primary.add (GenderChoice); 
    primary.add (Male); 
    primary.add (Female); 
}

public JPanel getGenderPanel()
{
    return primary;
}

private class GenderCount implements ActionListener
{ 
    public void GenderIsStored (ActionEvent event)
    { 
        Object source = event.getSource(); 

        if (Male.isSelected())
        { 
            MaleCount++; 
        } 

        else 
            FemaleCount++; 
    }

}
```

}

Comment: In the future, please search on your error as this has been [well asked and answered previously](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+class+is+not+abstract+and+does+not+override+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GenderCount` clearly doesn't implement `ActionListener`.

You need an`actionPerformed()`. Actually looks like you have one, but you have given it the wrong name: `GenderIsStored` instead of `actionPerformed`